# Eigen - maxCoeff causes compiler to crash

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, clang++

I am using library Eigen for some high performance computing with matrices and I wanted to get maximal element from an matrix `centers` defined as `Eigen::MatrixXi centers(A.rows(), 1);` (where A is also an matrix). For this reason I called

```
std::cout << centers.maxCoeff();
```

but when I tried to compile it with clang++ (version 3.5), when makefile was doing

```
clang++ -shared -fPIC build/snf.bc -o snf.so
```

the compiler gave me this error message:

```
clang++ -shared -fPIC build/snf.bc -o snf.so
fatal error: error in backend: Cannot select: 0x4815390: v4i32 = X86ISD::SMAX 0x4812860, 0x4979e70 [ORD=20] [ID=23]
  0x4812860: v4i32 = bitcast 0x4a2be70 [ORD=17] [ID=22]
    0x4a2be70: v2i64,ch = load 0x4812660, 0x4812960, 0x496fb30<LD16[%1]> [ORD=17] [ID=21]
      0x4812960: i64 = FrameIndex<0> [ID=6]
      0x496fb30: i64 = undef [ID=3]
  0x4979e70: v4i32 = bitcast 0x4a2c270 [ORD=19] [ID=16]
    0x4a2c270: v2i64,ch = load 0x4a2c170, 0x4812c60, 0x496fb30<LD16[%7]> [ORD=13] [ID=14] dbg:/usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/arch/SSE/PacketMath.h:194:10
      0x4812c60: i64,ch = CopyFromReg 0x2d19a10, 0x4813060 [ORD=8] [ID=11]
        0x4813060: i64 = Register %vreg3 [ID=4]
      0x496fb30: i64 = undef [ID=3]
In function: _ZN5Eigen8internal4pmaxIDv2_xEET_RKS3_S5_
clang: error: clang frontend command failed with exit code 70 (use -v to see invocation)
Ubuntu clang version 3.5-1ubuntu1 (trunk) (based on LLVM 3.5)
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
```

Please can you give me any suggestions what might be the problem? I never got internal compiler error before.

Comment: Can you come up with a way to reproduce this internal compiler error without throwing your entire project into the compiler?  It looks like it's happening during LTO; anyway, the CLang folks want to hear about these sorts of sparks!  Also, try injecting the -v flag into your build as the clang error message suggests, and posting the output here.